# React- Passing value from previous form page to next form page to show and to set value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, setstate

Hi I meet a problem that struggles me so many days.

I would like to get the value which generates from previous page and pass it to next page to show and to use.

In the previous page:

```
import React, {useState,useEffect} from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useDispatch, useSelector} from 'react-redux'
import { Table,Row, Col, ListGroup, Image, Form, Button, Card,FormGroup,Dropdown,DropdownButton,ProgressBar } from 'react-bootstrap'
import Message from '../components/Message'
import { uploadImage,uploadVisitForm,uploadAppliedForm,generateCaseNo,listStudentPhotos,addCase } from '../actions/caseActions'
import { listStudent } from '../actions/studentActions'
import Loader from '../components/Loader'
import CheckoutSteps from '../components/CheckoutSteps'
function CaseFinanceCreateScreen({history}) {
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    
    
    const [studentId, setStudentId] = useState()
    const [caseNumber, setCaseNumber] = useState()
    const [image, setImage] = useState(null)

    const [visitFormImage,setVisitFormImage]=useState(null)
    const [appliedFormImage,setAppliedFormImage]=useState(null)
    const [visitImageList,setVisitImageList]=useState(null)
    const uploadVisitPhotosAdd = useSelector(state => state.uploadVisitPhotosAdd)
    const { error, loading, visitPhotos } = uploadVisitPhotosAdd


    const uploadVisitFormAdd = useSelector(state => state.uploadVisitFormAdd)
    const { visitfromerror, visitfromloading, visitForm } = uploadVisitFormAdd


    const uploadAppliedFormAdd = useSelector(state => state.uploadAppliedFormAdd)
    const { appliederror, appliedloading, appliedForm } = uploadAppliedFormAdd
  
    const studentAdd = useSelector(state => state.studentAdd)
    const {erroradd, loadingadd, student} = studentAdd

    const genCaseNo = useSelector(state => state.genCaseNo)
    const { genError, genLoading, caseNo } = genCaseNo
    
    const getCaseFilesList = useSelector(state => state.getCaseFilesList)
    const { filerror, fileloading, files } = getCaseFilesList
    
    const caseAdd = useSelector(state => state.caseAdd)
    const { caseerror, caseloading, caseData } = caseAdd
    

    useEffect(() =>{
        
        setStudentId(studentAdd.student.id)
        dispatch(generateCaseNo(studentAdd.student['id']))
        setCaseNumber(genCaseNo.caseNo)
        localStorage.removeItem('visit_photo')
    },[])

    useEffect(() =>{
    dispatch(listStudentPhotos(studentAdd.student.id))
    },[dispatch,visitPhotos,visitForm,appliedForm])
 

    const handleInputVisitChange =(event) =>{

        event.preventDefault();
      
        setImage(
            event.target.files[0]
           );
       
    }
    const uploadImgurVisitPhotos = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        var data = new FormData(); 
        
        data.append("image", image); // add your file to form data
        data.append("type","訪視照片");
        data.append("name_id",studentAdd.student.id)
        dispatch(uploadImage(data))
        dispatch(listStudentPhotos(studentAdd.student.id))
        
    }

    const handleInputVisitFormChange =(event) =>{

        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(event.target.files[0])
        setVisitFormImage(
            event.target.files[0]
           );
       
    }
    const uploadImgurVisitFormPhotos = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        var data = new FormData(); 
        console.log(visitFormImage)
        data.append("image", visitFormImage); // add your file to form data
        data.append("type","訪視表");
        data.append("name_id",studentAdd.student.id)
        dispatch(uploadVisitForm(data))
        dispatch(listStudentPhotos(studentAdd.student.id))
        
    }


    const handleInputAppliedFormChange =(event) =>{

        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(event.target.files[0])
        setAppliedFormImage(
            event.target.files[0]
           );
       
    }
    const uploadImgurAppliedFormPhotos = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        var data = new FormData(); 
        console.log(appliedFormImage)
        data.append("image", appliedFormImage); // add your file to form data
        data.append("type","申請表");
        data.append("name_id",studentAdd.student.id)
        dispatch(uploadAppliedForm(data))
        dispatch(listStudentPhotos(studentAdd.student.id))
        
    }

    

    

    const saveCaseNo =() =>{
        
        console.log(studentId)
        console.log(caseNo)
        dispatch(addCase(studentId,caseNo))
        
        history.push('/case/createfinance')
        
    }
    
    
    return (
        <Row>
            <CheckoutSteps step1 step2/>
            <Col md={8}>
                <h3>
                產生案號:{caseNo}
                </h3>
                
                <div id="linksave">


                </div>
                <h3>上傳區</h3>
                <Card className="my-3 p-3 rounded">
                <h2>訪談照片</h2>

                    <form onSubmit={uploadImgurVisitPhotos}>
                    <input type="file" name="image" onChange={handleInputVisitChange}/>
                    <input type='submit'/>
                    </form> 
                  
                    
                    
                <h2>訪視表</h2>

                    <form onSubmit={uploadImgurVisitFormPhotos}>
                    <input type="file" name="visitform" onChange={handleInputVisitFormChange}/>
                    <input type='submit'/>
                    </form> 
                    

                <h2>申請表</h2>

                    <form onSubmit={uploadImgurAppliedFormPhotos}>
                    <input type="file" name="appliedform" onChange={handleInputAppliedFormChange}/>
                    <input type='submit'/>
                    </form> 
                    </Card>   
                    <br/>
                    {fileloading ? <Loader/>
            : filerror ? <Message variant='danger'>{filerror}</Message>
                : 
                <Row>
                    <Table striped bordered hover responsive className='table-sm'>
                    <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>動作</th>
                            
                                <th>種類</th>
                                <th>連結</th>
                                <th>預覽圖</th>
                               
                               
                                
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                    <tbody>

                    {files.map(file => (
                                <tr key={file._id}>
                                    <td>
                                    <Button
                                    type='button'
                                    variant='danger'
                        
                                    onClick={''}><i className='fas fa-trash'> </i>
                                    </Button>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>{file.type}</td>
                                    <td><Link href={file.link}>{file.link}</Link></td>
                                    <td><Image src={file.link} thumbnail /></td>
                            
                                </tr>
                            ))}
                    </tbody>
                    </Table>
                    </Row>
}
                    <Button type='button' variant='primary' onClick={saveCaseNo}>
                    儲存，下一步
                </Button>
                <Row className='py-3'>
                <Col>
                     <Link to='/case'>
                     取消
                        </Link>
                </Col>
            </Row>
                
            </Col>
            
            <ProgressBar animated now={40} label={`40%`}/>
            
            
        </Row>
        
    )
}
export default CaseFinanceCreateScreen
```

I use the new student Id to upload image, then I want to get this new student id and new case Id at next page when initial page loading.

How can I get the new value when the next new page loading and pass it into the React-Bootstrap Form.control fields?

Here are my next page code.
I would like to set the to_whom value from the Redux component `caseAdd` and show this value into the <Form.Group controlId='to_whom'> , which is readonly type.

```
function CaseFinanceCreateScreen({history}) {
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const [image, setImage] = useState(null)
 
    
    const [categoryName, setCategoryName] = useState('請選擇傳票票號')
    const [titleName, setTitleName] = useState('請選擇支出項目')
    const [to_whomName, setTo_whomName] = useState('請選擇個案')
    const [confirmed_personName, setConfirmed_personName] = useState('請選擇經手人')
    const [category, setCategory] = useState('')
    const [title, setTitle] = useState('')
    const [to_whom, setTo_whom] = useState('')
    const [confirmed_person, setConfirmed_person] = useState('')
    const [subject, setSubject] = useState('')
    const [detail, setDetail] = useState('')
    const [outcome_money, setOutcome_money] = useState('')
    const [unit, setUnit] = useState('NTD')
    const [save, setSave] = useState('')
  
    //const redirect = location.search ? location.search.split('=')[1] :'/school'
    const redirect = '/case/createscholarship'


    const outcomeAdd = useSelector(state => state.outcomeAdd)
    const {error, loading, outcome} = outcomeAdd


    const outcomeContributeContextList = useSelector(state => state.outcomeContributeContextList)
    const { errorincomeContribute, loadingincomeContribute, outcomeContributeContext } = outcomeContributeContextList

    const outcomeMoneyCategoryList = useSelector(state => state.outcomeMoneyCategoryList)
    const { erroroutcomeMoneyCategoryList, loadingoutcomeMoneyCategoryList, outcomeMoneyCategory} = outcomeMoneyCategoryList
    
    const memberList = useSelector(state => state.memberList)
    const { errorList, loadingList, members } = memberList

    
    const studentDetailReducer = useSelector(state => state.studentDetail)
    const { errorstudent, loadingstudent, student } = studentDetailReducer

    const caseAdd = useSelector(state => state.caseAdd)
    const { caseerror, caseloading, caseData } = caseAdd

    const prevCase = useRef("");
    
    
    
    useEffect(()=>{
        
        prevCase.current = caseData;
        console.log(prevCase)
        
        dispatch(listMember())
     
        setTo_whom(prevCase.student_name)
       
        
    },[outcome,history,caseData,caseAdd])
    
    useEffect(()=>{
        
        
        //setTo_whom(prevCase.student_name)
        //setSave(prevCase.student_name)
       
        console.log("to_whom=",to_whom)
       
    },[to_whom])


    const handleSelectCategory=(e)=>{
        
        var splitCategory = e.split(',');
        setCategory(splitCategory[0])

        setCategoryName(splitCategory[1]);  
        
      }

      

      const handleSelectTitle=(e)=>{
        
        var splitTitle = e.split(',');
        setTitle(splitTitle[0])

        setTitleName(splitTitle[1]); 
        
        
      }
      
      

      const handleSelectConfirm_person=(e)=>{
        
        var splitTitle = e.split(',');
        setConfirmed_person(splitTitle[0])

        setConfirmed_personName(splitTitle[1]); 
        
        
      }
    const submitHandler =(e) =>{
        e.preventDefault()
        
        dispatch(addOutcome(category,title, to_whom, confirmed_person, subject, detail, outcome_money, unit))
        
        history.push(redirect)
        
    }
    return (
        <FormContainer>
            <h1>案號：</h1>
            <h1>新增支出</h1>
            
            {error && <Message variant='danger'>{error}</Message>}
            {loading && <Loader />}
            
            <Form onSubmit={submitHandler}>

            <Form.Group controlId='category'>
                    <Form.Label>傳票號數</Form.Label>
                    <DropdownButton
                aligndown="true"
                title= {categoryName}
                id="dropdown-menu-align-down"
                onSelect={handleSelectCategory}
                    >

            {outcomeMoneyCategory.map((category,index) =>{
            
            return <Dropdown.Item eventKey={[category._id,category.name]} key={index}>{category.name}</Dropdown.Item>
            })}
                       
            </DropdownButton>
            </Form.Group>

            <Form.Group controlId='title'>
                    <Form.Label>內容</Form.Label>
                    <DropdownButton
                aligndown="true"
                title= {titleName}
                id="dropdown-menu-align-down"
                onSelect={handleSelectTitle}
                    >

            {outcomeContributeContext.map((title,index) =>{
            
            return <Dropdown.Item eventKey={[title._id,title.context]} key={index}>{title.context}</Dropdown.Item>
            })}
                       
            </DropdownButton>
            </Form.Group>

            <Form.Group controlId='subject'>
                    <Form.Label>科目</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control
                        required
                        type='name'
                        placeholder='輸入科目'
                        value={subject}
                        onChange={(e) => setSubject(e.target.value)}
                    >

                    </Form.Control>
            </Form.Group>

            <Form.Group controlId='represent_person_phone'>
                    <Form.Label>摘要</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control
                        required
                        type='detail'
                        placeholder='輸入摘要'
                        value={detail}
                        onChange={(e) => setDetail(e.target.value)}
                    >

                    </Form.Control>
            </Form.Group>
          
          
            <Form.Group controlId='to_whom'>
                    <Form.Label>個案姓名</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control
                    
                        type='text'
                        //value={prevCase.current.student.name}
                        value={to_whom}
                        readOnly
                        
                    />
                         
                    
                    
            </Form.Group>
            <Form.Group controlId='outcome_money'>
                    <Form.Label>支出金額</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control
                        required
                        type='outcome'
                        placeholder='填入金額'
                        value={outcome_money}
                        onChange={(e) => setOutcome_money(e.target.value)}
                    >

                    </Form.Control>
            </Form.Group>
            <Form.Group controlId='unit'>
                    <Form.Label>單位</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control
                        type='unit'
                        placeholder='預設 新台幣 NTD'
                        value={unit}
                        onChange={(e) => setUnit(e.target.value)}
                    >

                    </Form.Control>
            </Form.Group>
            
            <Form.Group controlId='confirmed_person'>
                    <Form.Label>審核人</Form.Label>
                    <DropdownButton
                        aligndown="true"
                        title= {confirmed_personName}
                        id="dropdown-menu-align-down"
                        onSelect={handleSelectConfirm_person}
                            >

                    {members.map((member,index) =>{
                    
                    return <Dropdown.Item eventKey={[member._id,member.name]} key={index}>{member.name}</Dropdown.Item>
                    })}
                            
                    </DropdownButton>
            </Form.Group>
                <Button type='submit' variant='primary'>
                    建立
                </Button>
            </Form>
        
            <Row className='py-3'>
                <Col>
                     <Link to='/case'>
                     取消
                        </Link>
                </Col>
            </Row>
        </FormContainer>
    )
}
export default CaseFinanceCreateScreen
```

I try to get value by `useRef` but it seems not to work properly.

Always show me messages like `TypeError: Cannot read property 'student_name' of undefined`.

I think this is React setState not synchronous so I can't get the value from first time loading time.

Thanks for your time.
Hope this is not too hard to understand what I want to describe it with my poor English.